# Insert data from form into database table (PDO)

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I have the following code here. It is meant to establish a database, connect to it, provide a user form with three fields ('name1', 'name2', 'digits'), and include two options for the form: If one of the three text box fields ('name1', 'name2', 'digits') is empty in the submission, then there should be a message to tell users which input is missing. If all three inputs are present, the input data is supposed to go into the table 'mytable' in the database and direct the user to another page.

As of now, the data is not inserted into the table, and the missing text box messages show up even when the submit button isn't pressed even when refreshing the page, based on a previous entry. Thanks for the help!

```
<?php
try{
$conn = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myuser','mydb','password');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' $e->getMessage ();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

}
?>  
</br>
<form action = "form" method="post">
</br>


Field1:<input type="text" id="name1" name="name1"><br/>
Field2:<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2"><br/>
Digits:<input type="text" id="digits" name="digits"><br/>
<input type="reset" name="reset">
<input type="submit" name="submit"></br>
</form>

<?php

$required = array(
'name1',
'name2',
'digits',
);
if(isset($_POST ['submit'])){
$i = 0;
foreach($required as $field)
if(empty($_POST ['$field'])){
echo "{$field} is required";}
echo "<br/>";
if($i==0) {
$q = "INSERT INTO mytable (name1, name2, digits) VALUES (:name1, :name2, :digits);";
$query = $conn->prepare($q);
$results = $query->execute(array(
":name1" => $name1,
":name2" => $name2,
":digits" => $digits
));
header ("Location: Secondpage.php");}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add else condition to the if clause which is in foreach loop. Assign value of POST to the variables $name1, $name2 and $digits

In else part add below line:

$$field = $_POST[$field];

Comment: in else part assign variable values. only one statement ex: $$field = $_POST[$field];

Answer (score 0):

You never assign a value to `$name1`, `$name2` or `$digits`.

Presumably you mean `$_POST['name1']` etc.